# Problem in output regarding taking the file name from user

Tags: python

So I tried to run the code trying to print the lines starting with "How" taking the file name from the user, but the output shows there are 0 lines starting with "How".

content in the file, read.txt-

```
Hey there, this is Sohail Hassan.
How are you?
How is everything going?
How is everything at college?
```

```
fhand = input("enter the file name")
try:
    fname = open(fhand)
except:
    print("can't open the file")


count = 0
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith("How"):
        count = count+1

print("There are,",count,"lines in this file.")
```

Comment: You want to do `for line in fname:`, not `for line in fhand:`.

Comment: Your variable names are backwards. The input should be named `fname`, and the file handle should be named `fhand`.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

Full corrected version of your code, with a few improvements:

```
fname = input("enter the file name")
try:
    with open(fname, 'w') as fhand:
        for line in fhand:
            if line.startswith("How"):
                count += 1
except:
    print("can't open the file '" + fname + "'")

print("There are " + count + " lines starting with 'How' in this file.")
```